# Override Magento\Catalog\Model\Product

Tags: magento2, product, override-model

I would like to add a new function to Product Model which be accessible each time I create Product.

Below, my code :

> src/app/code/Project/Catalog/Model/Product.php :

```
<?php

namespace Project\Catalog\Model;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{
    public function newFunction()
    {
     // myfunction
    }
}
```

> src/app/code/Project/Catalog/etc/di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface" type="Project\Catalog\Model\Product" />
</config>
```

> src/app/code/Project/Catalog/Block/Block.php

```
<?php

namespace Project\Catalog\Block;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;

class Block extends Template
{
    public function newFunction()
    {
        return $this->_currentProduct->newFunction();
    }
}
```

But I got the following exception :

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid
>   method Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor::newFunction

Why my new function is not find ? Where am I wrong ?

Comment: can't find the method `isProductNew` in your code

Comment: Sorry, bad copy/paste : it's not isProductNew, it's newFunction

Comment: did you run compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do the below change in your di.xml file and confirm.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="Project\Catalog\Model\Product" />
</config>
```

Comment: You're right, that work ! But how can I override the public function __construct() of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product ? I need to add something in, but when I try to call parrent::__construct, I don't know what I need to put in param..

Comment: You can create type node di.xml file to supply additional arguments to the class without disturbing the construct function. May i know the reason why you want to change the construct() function ?